# Typeclass resolution and autorewrite

Tags: coq

I have a base of rewrite lemmas. Some of them are parameterized by typeclasses. When applying a lemma, it is important that the rewrite fails when the typeclass cannot be automatically resolved by Coq. The only way I have found to get this behaviour is to declare most of the parameters implicit.

```
Class T (t:Type) : Type.
Instance T1 : T nat.
Instance T2 : forall {A1 A2:Type} {t1:T A1} {t2:T A2}, T (A1*A2).

Definition f {A:Type} (x:A) := x.

Lemma f_eq : forall {A:Type} (t:T A) (x:A), f x = x.
Proof.
  reflexivity.
Qed.

Lemma test1 : f (0,1) = (0,1).
Proof.
  rewrite f_eq.
  (* a subgoal T (nat * nat) is generated,
     which should have been resolved directly *)
Abort.

Lemma test2 : f (0,true) = (0,true).
Proof.
  rewrite f_eq.
  (* a subgoal T (nat * bool) is generated,
     while it should have failed *)
Abort.

Arguments f_eq {_ _} _.

Lemma test1 : f (0,1) = (0,1).
Proof.
  rewrite f_eq.
  reflexivity. (* OK *)
Qed.

Lemma test2 : f (0,true) = (0,true).
Proof.
  Fail rewrite f_eq. (* fails as expected *)
Abort.
```

Then I want to add my lemmas to a rewrite database, but the lemma added to the database is already specialized.

```
Hint Rewrite f_eq : my_db.

Print Rewrite HintDb my_db.
(* Database my_db
   rewrite -> f_eq of type forall x : nat, f x = x *)
```

How can I add my lemmas to a rewrite database and get the proper behaviour in terms of typeclass resolution of their arguments ?

EDIT: there is an option `Set Typeclass Resolution After Apply.` that seems to enable the behaviour that I expect, but only for `apply`, not `rewrite`.
The corresponding commit gives the following description:

> Add an option to solve typeclass goals generated by apply which can't
>   be catched otherwise due to the discrepancy between evars and metas.

Comment: FWIW, if you used this `Definition f {A:Type} {t : T A} (x:A) := x.`, you'd be able to use rewrite hints and you wouldn't be abled to even state `Lemma test2 : f (0,true) = (0,true).`

Answer (score 6):

One possible solution is to use ssreflect's rewrite (this will fix the first part of the problem) and replace the hint db by multi-rewrite rules. That is to say:

```
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect.

Class T (t:Type) : Type.
Instance T1 : T nat.
Instance T2 : forall {A1 A2:Type} {t1:T A1} {t2:T A2}, T (A1*A2).

Definition f {A:Type} (x:A) := x.

Lemma f_eq : forall {A:Type} (t : T A) (x:A), f x = x.
Proof. by []. Qed.

(* Add more lemmas as needed *)
Definition my_db A := (@f_eq A, @f_eq A).

Lemma test1 : f (0,1) = (0,1).
Proof. by rewrite my_db. Qed.

Lemma test2 : f (0,true) = (0,true).
Proof.
Fail rewrite f_eq.
Abort.
```

Comment: I am impressed by the error message of the second rewrite (`Error: The LHS of f_eq (f _) matches but type classes inference fails`) which could not be clearer, but I would prefer a solution without ssreflect.

Comment: What I do not understand is the difference of treatment of typeclass resolution between standard rewrite and ssreflect's rewrite. As explained in my post, when using typeclasses with standard rewrite, I always need to play with the implicitness of parameters to force resolution. With ssreflect's rewrite, it seems that it always work.

Comment: @eponier there are different tactics and work in a quite different way AFAICT.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a workaround. First, we add the *generalized* lemma, but we tell the `autorewrite` tactic to use the tactic `exact _` to solve the secondary goal of resolving the necessary typeclass instance.

```
Hint Rewrite @f_eq using (exact _): my_db.
Print Rewrite HintDb my_db.
(*
  Database my_db
  rewrite -> @f_eq of type forall A : Type, T A -> forall x : A, f x = x
  then use tactic exact _
*)
```

Then you can keep rewriting with `rewrite` as you've shown in the body of your question, or you can use your database:

```
Lemma test1' : f (0,1) = (0,1).
Proof.
  autorewrite with my_db.
  reflexivity.
Qed.

Lemma test2 : f (0,true) = (0,true).
Proof.
  autorewrite with my_db.
  (* does nothing: no rewrites, no error messages *)
Abort.
```

Notice that when we use `exact _` Coq does *not* generate new instances of the form `Build_T (nat * bool)` in the last case, as it would do if we used `reflexivity` instead.
Here is an example of what I mean by that. If we started with this hint

```
Hint Rewrite @f_eq using reflexivity: my_db.
```

we could prove `test2` this way

```
Lemma test2 : f (0,true) = (0,true).
Proof.
  autorewrite with my_db.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

But if we look at it using `Set Printing All. Print test2.` we will see that Coq constructed a *new instance* of `T`: `(Build_T (prod nat bool))` which I think goes against your goal -- it seems you'd prefer Coq to infer an already existing instance of `T` if it's possible at all or fail in some way.

We can repeat the same thing manually:

```
Lemma test2' : f (0,true) = (0,true).
Proof.
  rewrite @f_eq. reflexivity.
  exact (Build_T (nat * bool)). (* `exact _` won't work *)
Qed.
```

Comment: This is interesting. My best try was `Hint Rewrite f_eq using typeclasses eauto : my_db.`, but according to me this should work directly. As for your last point about `reflexivity`, I do not understand why it works and what it does.

Comment: @eponier I've tried to explain what I meant about `reflexivity`.

Comment: Thank you, it is clearer. Actually, I had forgotten that typeclasses were basically records, and that a record without any field can be instantiated quite easily. Indeed, it is something that I would like to avoid in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct, but it seems that `apply _` uses existing typeclass instances instead of rebuilding them.  So `Hint Rewrite f_eq using apply _ : my_db` maybe does what you want.